# Vue filter by multiple types with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This single 'type' filter works but how would you turn this single select a 'Type' to multiple types with checkboxes? Ideally the items would have multiple types assignable, and work with an axios request to a separate json file, but single type and this json would do for now as I am only just learning.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    startDate:null,
    endDate:null,
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country:'belgium',
        date: '08/11/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/21/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterItem: function () {
      
      let filterType = this.selectedType
      if (!filterType) return this.items;  // when filterType not selected

      let startDate = this.startDate && new Date(this.startDate);
      let endDate = this.endDate && new Date(this.endDate);
      
      return this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.type == filterType;
      }).filter(item => {
        const itemDate = new Date(item.date)
        if (startDate && endDate) {
          return startDate <= itemDate && itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        if (startDate && !endDate) {
          return startDate <= itemDate;
        }
        if (!startDate && endDate) {
          return itemDate <= endDate;
        }
        return true;  // when neither startDate nor endDate selected
      })
      
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

span {
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-box {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button {
  background-color: #1cf478;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

select,input {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="">Type</label>
  <select v-model="selectedType">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="">From</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="startDate">
  
  <label for="">To</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="endDate">
  
  <div class="list-item" v-for="item in filterItem">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Date: {{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide some [mcve] and details about the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straight forward way to achieve this is by using `multiple` attribute in your select element and to select multiple options user have to hold down the `Ctrl (windows)` or `Command (Mac)` button to select multiple options and then do filtering based on the multiple selection.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: [],
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country:'belgium',
        date: '08/11/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/21/2020'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england',
        date: '08/01/2020'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterItem: function () {
      let filterType = this.selectedType
      if (!filterType.length) return this.items;
      
      return this.items.filter(item => {
        return filterType.includes(item.type);
      })
      
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="">Type</label>
  <select v-model="selectedType" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>
  
  <div class="list-item" v-for="item in filterItem">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Date: {{ item.date }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note **:** If you want to select multiple options using checkbox only then you can use any 3rd party libraries available in the market.

Comment: Just set up some checkboxes with the same v-model and works perfectly!

Comment: That's great @Crashdesk , Nice to hear this